# How to setup an application state by sending messages in Kafka integration tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to integration test my application using testcontainers for the Kafka binding.

In the following scenario the test setup never gets past `waitForMessagesToBeDelivered` which waits forever for the entities to be created after the messages have been received. In my understanding it's supposed to deliver two messages through Kafka which ought to be received by `MyConsumer` which should then create two `MyEntity`s which should increase the value returned by `myEntityRepository.count()`.

In a similar scenario for which I created this reproduction setup, one message of two is received and an entity created for it.

```
@Service
public class MyConsumer {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyConsumer.class);
    private final MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    public static final String TOPIC_ENTITIES = "entities";

    @Autowired
    public MyConsumer(MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository) {
        this.myEntityRepository = myEntityRepository;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = TOPIC_ENTITIES, groupId = "MyEntity")
    public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> %s", message));
        MyEntityCreatedMessage deserializedMessage = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(message, MyEntityCreatedMessage.class);
        myEntityRepository.save(new MyEntity(deserializedMessage.getUuid()));
        LOGGER.info("persisted created entity with uuid {}",
                deserializedMessage.getUuid());
    }
}
```

and a

```
@Configuration
public class MySpringKafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topicEntities() {
        return new NewTopic(TOPIC_ENTITIES, 10, (short) 2);
    }
}
```

which I want to test with

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MySpringKafkaApplication.class})
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = MyConsumerIT.TestcontainersInitializer.class)
@Testcontainers
public class MyConsumerIT {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyConsumerIT.class);
    private static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer();
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final UUID ENTITY1_UUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    private static final UUID ENTITY2_UUID = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUpClass() {
        kafkaContainer.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDownClass() {
        kafkaContainer.stop();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {
        final String serializedMessage = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new MyEntityCreatedMessage(ENTITY1_UUID));
        kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC_ENTITIES, serializedMessage);
        final String serializedMessageAdmin = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new MyEntityCreatedMessage(ENTITY2_UUID));
        kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC_ENTITIES, serializedMessageAdmin);
        waitForMessagesToBeDelivered();
    }

    private void waitForMessagesToBeDelivered() throws InterruptedException {
        while(myEntityRepository.count() != 2) {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("userRepository.count: %d",
                    myEntityRepository.count()));
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomethingWhichRequiresTwoMyEntities() {
    }

    /* default */ static class TestcontainersInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            String kafkaContainerBootstrapServers = kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers();
            LOGGER.info("kafkaContainerBootstrapServers: {}",
                    kafkaContainerBootstrapServers);
            TestPropertyValues
                    .of("spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=" + kafkaContainerBootstrapServers)
                    .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
            TestPropertyValues
                    .of("spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=" + kafkaContainerBootstrapServers)
                    .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }
}
```

In the [logs](https://pastebin.com/nD4irfNe) I'm seeing

```
2019-11-15 17:01:44.575 ERROR 30056 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not configure topics

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing topics; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

but then the connection seems to succeed, I'm not sure though.

I'm aware of alternatives like embedded kafka, but I'd like to work with testcontainers in order to increase the authenticity of the integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race between sending the messages and the consumer starting. By default, new Kafka consumers start consuming from the end of the topic.

Adding:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

will ensure the consumer gets any existing records in the topic.